# hierarchical query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, recursive-query

I have hierarchical table name `dept_employees` with structure below:

```
--------------------------------------
| id | parent_id | obj_id | obj_type |
--------------------------------------
| 1  |    null   |    34  |   dept   |
--------------------------------------
| 2  |       3   |    78  |   agent  |
--------------------------------------
| 3  |       1   |    78  | employee |
--------------------------------------
| 4  |       2   |   79   |   agent  |
--------------------------------------
| 5  |       3   |   80   |   agent  |
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
|1500|       2   |   934  | employee |
--------------------------------------
|1501|       4   |   935  | employee |
--------------------------------------
```

if `obj_type = 'agent'`

I need tak it from another table named `Agents`, `Agents` looks like:

```
--------------------------------------
| id |    name   |  phone |  Adress  |
--------------------------------------
| 1  |   Shynaz  |   123  |   Almaty |
--------------------------------------
| 2  |   Damir   |   589  |   Astana |
--------------------------------------
| 3  |   Oljas   |   637  | Karagand |
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
| 78 |   Erasyl  |   743  |   Aktau  |
--------------------------------------
| 79 |   Erok    |   743  |   Atyrau |
--------------------------------------
```

Or if `obj_type = 'employee'`, then i need take it from another table named `Employees`. Employees looks like:

```
--------------------------------------
| id |    name   |  office |  salary |
--------------------------------------
| 1  |   Asyl    |   123  |   1000$  |
--------------------------------------
| 2  |   Zhandos |   589  |   1500$  |
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
| 78 |   Aleksei |   637  |    500$  |
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
|934|   Alibi   |   7    |    980$  |
--------------------------------------
|935|   Azat    |   8    |    980$  |
--------------------------------------
```

In first table `parent_id` is `id` in the same table, but in another record.
For example: I get all child `agents` and `employeers` of record that `id = 2`.
I need output like:

```
------------
id | name  |
------------
79 | Erok  |
------------
934| Alibi |
------------
```

And my query is:

```
WITH ChildNodes(id, name) 
AS(
SELECT 
   parent_de.id, 
   case parent_de.obj_type
    When 'agent' then parent_l.Name
    When 'employee' then parent_e.Fullname
   end as name
FROM FstP_Restored.dbo.dept_employees parent_de
left Join FstP_Restored.dbo.employees parent_e
    On parent_de.obj_id = parent_e.id --and parent_de.obj_type = 'employee'
left Join Agents_Restored.dbo.Лица parent_l 
    On parent_de.obj_id = parent_l.ID --and parent_de.obj_type = 'agent'
WHERE parent_de.id = 2--and parent_de.obj_type = isnull('agent', 'employees')

UNION ALL
SELECT
   child_de.id, 
   case child_de.obj_type
    When 'agent' then child_l.Name
    When 'employee' then child_e.Fullname
   end as name
FROM FstP_Restored.dbo.dept_employees child_de
 Inner Join FstP_Restored.dbo.employees child_e 
    On child_de.obj_id = child_e.id --and child_de.obj_type = 'employee' 
 Inner Join Agents_Restored.dbo.Лица child_l
    On child_de.obj_id = child_l.ID --and child_de.obj_type = 'agent'
 Inner JOIN ChildNodes parent ON parent.id = child_de.parent_id)

SELECT 
ChildNodes.id, 
ChildNodes.name
FROM ChildNodes
Where ChildNodes.id!= 2
```

With this query i got nothing. What i do wrong?
SQL Server 2014

Comment: Please tag the version of SQL - is it SQL Server?

Comment: I haven't gone through in detail but do each of the components of your query return data? Does the very first query on it's own return data? You might need to use an outer join if the agent join is optional (i.e. not every employee is an agent)

Comment: Шыназ Алиш, Please, read some books about DB and SQL

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but seems to be a simple thing, doesn't it? Can be extended for more object types.

```
SELECT
    t1.obj_id AS id,
    CASE t1.obj_type
        WHEN 'agent' THEN t2.name
        WHEN 'employee' THEN t3.name
        ELSE 'unknown'
    AS name
FROM dept_employees t1
LEFT JOIN Agents t2 ON t1.obj_id=t2.id
LEFT JOIN Employees t3 ON t1.obj_id=t3.id
WHERE t1.parent_id=2
```

Comment: Thanks, you are corrected one of the my errors)). But in some cases hierarchy displayed, in some cases not displayed.